# Grease Pencil looks bad

Tags: materials, grease-pencil, scale, 2d, resolution

So i just started trying out the grease pencil and it looks terrible. very low resolution and its jagged. the pencil dose not overlap it cuts through previous strokes, anyone have any tips on how to fix this? I'm using a Wacom tablet if that affects anything. EDIT: It seems to work fine when i'm not drawing on a surface 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to check and make sure the jitter is a low value and the curve for jitter is linear. Also perhaps try increasing the number of samples.
[image]

Comment: That helped with the jagged problem but when ever i turn the brush to draw a round object it messes up again, also it still cuts through other lines.